# Can we fetch data from third-party database using aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am looking for two days now, but can't find anything.
Please help me out

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Lambda is just code running on "serverless" technology.  [Lambda supports Phython, Java and Node.js.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model-v2.html) So your question is really more about those particular languages than Lambda.  After that you just need to have access to those databases and you should be all set.